# Weak form of heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: heat-equation, bilinear-form

I'm trying to wrap my head around the ways to approach the heat problem. This time, with Neumann boundary conditions. Now, I have the theory down, but the only example I found leaves me behind by leaping to the solution without any mention of the process used to get there. So here it is:

I want the weak form of: $$- \biggl( {u' \over x^2+1} \biggl)'+u=e^x$$  $$u'(0)=u'(1)=0$$
defined in $(0,1)$

The solution simply whips out a formula that is basically the Lax-Milgram theorem $$\int_0^1 \biggl[ {1 \over x^2+1}u'v'+uv\biggl]dx=\int_0^1e^xvdx$$

Which of course guarantees the existence of one solution, assuming that the bilinear form is continuous and coercive and the functional is continuous. It makes sense, but what are the steps in between the starting and the ending points?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply your equation formally by a test function $v\in H^1$ and integrate by parts
$$
-\int_0^1\left(\frac{u'}{1+x^2}\right)'v\,dx+\int_0^1 uv\,dx=\int_0^1 e^xv\,dx,
$$
$$
\int_0^1\left(\frac{u'}{1+x^2}\right)v'\,dx-\left(\frac{u'}{1+x^2}\right)v|_0^1+\int_0^1 uv\,dx=\int_0^1 e^xv\,dx.
$$
Using the boundary condition the non-integral term cancels and you get your weak form of the equation.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense, thank you very much. If you don't mind, I have a few follow up questions: 
1) is it a coincidence that integrating by parts and applying the boundary conditions is essentially  like using the derivative property of any tested linear functional? i.e. $\langle  f', \phi \rangle = - \langle f, \phi ' \rangle$?
2) I assume that the only reason I can seek out this form is because I have those initial conditions. If I were to have Dirichlet's conditions instead, how would the approach change?
3) The form is weak because it came from a test function, right?

Comment: Question 1) is probably a yes, since with different conditions that non-integral term wouldn't cancel.

Comment: I do not think it is a coincidence. The idea of weakening the concept of solution by multiplying by a "test" and integrating by parts in such a way that the derivatives are now applied to the test and less regularity is required of the solution, which has been used in PDEs for a long time, naturally leads to defining "weak" derivatives in the sense of distributions. In case of Dirichlet condition, the same computation works with $v\in H^1_0$ (you start with $v\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ and extend by density). The form is weak because it makes sense for less regular $u$'s (in some Sobolev space).

Comment: Wonderful, I think I got it. Thank you very much once again.